# TypeScript not enabled in Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, typescript

I have 3 of the Express versions of Visual Studio 2012 installed:

- Web
- Windows Desktop
- Windows 8

I have installed TypeScript via the MSI but it is only enabled in the Web edition. In the other 2 editions it does not show up under Tools and Extensions, and there is no TypeScript item available when I choose Add New Item.

When I run TypeScriptLanguageService.vsix from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0 it tells me that it is already installed for all applicable products.

From my web searches I'm unclear on whether it is meant to be available in the Windows 8 edition. I've been using it in the Web edition and loving it and I'd really like to try it in a Javascript Windows 8 store app.

Comment: The language service is an add-in.  The Express edition doesn't support add-ins.

Comment: But the Web version of Express does? This seems strange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the system requirements on the [plugin's download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790). They list explicitly all the supported VS editions. Seems to be a deliberate choice not to support the other Express editions.

Comment: Dang, how did I not find that? Thank you. Well, this is an unfortunate decision on Microsoft's part. Since these products are free I shouldn't complain too much, but given that they are already facing a massive challenge to achieve credible scale in the tablet and app space, this doesn't exactly encourage folks with a mostly web background to test the waters with their app development. I also work a bit with WPF and Silverlight, so I could write a XAML / C# app, but as HTML5 is my core career focus and I want to use TypeScript, I probably won't bother for now.

Comment: Maybe it's not their last word - TypeScript is still an alpha version (look at http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/397600 and guess what trouble they might have had).  Given the fact that you can write Windows 8 apps in JavaScript it surely would make a lot of sense to support TS in VS for W8, too. In the meantime: could it be a workaround to type the TS code with the Web Edition and import the generated JS files into a W8 app project in the W8 Edition?

Answer (score 0):

btw Typescript is already enabled for Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web.